# HTML to PDF conversion using iText

Tags: java, itext

I'm trying to convert an HTMLl file to PDF.  For that I'm using [iText](http://itextpdf.com/).  If the HTML has some image in its body, iText fails to put that image in the PDF and it throws the following exception.

> `ExceptionConverter: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\cid:870001313@01022011-2B8B (The system cannot find the file specified).`

If the HTML has some image in its body, is it possible to read that image and make it as attachment to that PDF file?  Here is my source code (Truncate.java):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import com.lowagie.text.Element;
import com.lowagie.text.Paragraph;
import com.lowagie.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class Truncate {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FileReader fr = null;
        Document document = new Document();
        document.open();
        PdfWriter writer = null;
        try {
            String file_name = "C:\\Documentum\\Viewed\\911.htm";
            fr = new FileReader(file_name);
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, System.out);
            writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(
                    "C:\\Documentum\\Viewed\\RH\\RH.pdf"));
            document.add(new Paragraph("RH Mail"));
            ArrayList htmlContentList = HTMLWorker.parseToList(fr, null);

            //fetch the html content line by line
            for (int htmlDataCntr = 0; htmlDataCntr < htmlContentList.size(); htmlDataCntr++) {
                Element htmlDataElement = (Element) htmlContentList
                        .get(htmlDataCntr);
                document.add(htmlDataElement);
            }
            fr.close();
            document.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the name of the attachment, it seems like your html is exported from an email. Make sure you should parse the email differently, and get the images apart from the other stuff.

EDIT : As I said, I think the problems lays upstream. The `cid` notation corresponds to an embedded image in a mail (see [here](http://pastebin.com/4862Hka4) for example). So, if the upsteam mail parser doesn't give you the image file as an attachment, you can't do anything about it.

Comment: Yes.  You are absolutely right.  We have vendor provided API (Documentum) which converts an e-mail to HTML document.  Then, we are parsing/converting this HTML document to PDF document using iText.  While we try to parse this HTML document we are getting the exception.

Comment: Like I said, the problem lays upstream. I'll provide some more explication in my answer.